# How to find the Linux distro used as the basis for an official docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I already think I understand that docker containers "share" the same Linux kernel running on their host. But inside a particular docker container, the software stack could be a distro debian, alpine, centos or ubuntu and on top of that various other software components, such as a web server, database, language interpreter etc.

Indeed there are official images for such distros.

But there are also official images for Apache ([httpd](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)) and PHP ([php](https://hub.docker.com/_/php))

My question is, how can I find out the default distro that these sit upon?

I ask, because for example, I've seen a Dockerfile which starts with:

`FROM php:7.2-fpm` (which is one of the official PHP images)

Followed by:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Source: [hub.docker.com/_/php](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) (see section "How to install more PHP extensions")

Also, what distro is used for the httpd (Apache) official image?

Comment: -1 downvote - why? The opinion might be that this might not be a valid question - but in any case the answer I give, provides the answer and suggests that a different question might be better to ask. I'd never downvote a question without giving a reason. In fact I've never downvoted a question, only provided constructive comments. Also credit me with giving my own answer (almost immediately after - benefit for all); I'm not a help vampire. Shame that the techie stereotype of limited communication skills is perpetuated by this negative score without reason. Thanks for your time reading though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote this question I found a link to the original source code for these official images, which answered my questions:

For example, for official image `php:7.2-fpm`, the base image is: [debian:stretch-slim](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile)

And for official Apache image, `httpd` it's [debian:buster-slim](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile)

So, to find out the distro upon which official images are based on, go here: https://github.com/docker-library

...and append your official image of interest to the URL.